# PostOrder Traversal Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to return a string representation of my tree after a post order traversal but it is giving me the works. Seems like a simple enough code but I can't seem to get it. Debugging isn't of much help either. I lose track of what I'm supposed to be looking at. What is going wrong here? 
I know using a string in this sense is bad practice but I was just throwing something together. I could have used a string buffer or something else but now I'm stumped as to why this is not working and would like to figure out the reason.

```
  public String postOrderTraversal(){
        String answer = "";
        return postOrderTraversal(root, answer);
    }

    private String postOrderTraversal(Node aux, String answer){
        if(aux == null){
            return "";
        }
        else{
            postOrderTraversal(aux.left, answer);
            postOrderTraversal(aux.right, answer);
            answer += aux.data;
        }

        return answer;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the post-order traversals of the subtrees. You can correct it as

```
private String postOrderTraversal(Node aux) {
    if(aux == null) return "";
    return postOrderTraversal(aux.left) + postOrderTraversal(aux.right) + aux.data;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. On my test it repeated the left child and root multiple times. It should have printed 2,5,6,10,9,4 but printed 2,2,2,2,5,6,2,2,2,5,6,10,9,4

Comment: You can try the modified code. You actually don't need to pass the string `answer` to recursive calls.

Comment: Yes. That works! Huh. So you don't actually need a string value to keep track of it all. I tried it with string buffer first and thought maybe the same approach would work for Strings too. Clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable objects. Just passing the reference won't update the return values. You should try StringBuilder.

```
public String postOrderTraversal(){
    StringBuilder answer  = new StringBuilder();
    postOrderTraversal(root, answer);
    return answer.toString();
}

private void postOrderTraversal(Node aux, StringBuilder answer){
    if(aux == null){
        return;
    }
    else{
        postOrderTraversal(aux.left, answer);
        postOrderTraversal(aux.right, answer);
        answer.append(aux.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to do it with a string builder. It was more of a why is it not working question and trying to understand it. Thanks for your input!